# Requirements for Integrating Thunderbolt 3 Into Product

Tags: embedded, interface, thunderbolt

Based on the bandwidth and relatively good availability of Thunderbolt 3 ports on PCs we are considering incorporating a Thunderbolt 3 interface into a new product.

My understanding is that the thunderbolt can interface a PCIe endpoint.

Intel has the [DSL6340 controller](https://ark.intel.com/products/87401/Intel-DSL6340-Thunderbolt-3-Controller) which is [available for purchase](https://www.mouser.com/productdetail/intel/dsl6340-sll3z?qs=sGAEpiMZZMuobhpKLk3hh%252bd2j3CAnusqhJlnCva9JIs%3D) from various vendors, but I haven't seen any accompanying development materials.

Is it possible to obtain development support material for Thunderbolt 3 if it's for a low-volume product? Is it feasible for a small company to develop a Thunderbolt 3 product?

Comment: Have you simply tried to contact intel?

Comment: To be honest I'm still figuring out *how* to contact them. This is what makes me think they only work with a massive company. Maybe someone here who's worked in the actual industry knows how these things work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request info on becoming a Thunderbolt developer at https://thunderbolttechnology.net/contact/thunderbolt-developer .  It says they will get back to you within 3 weeks.  As long as you are a company and/or startup, they should at least talk to you.  It will help if you have a company email and/or website.  If you are currently buying parts from any distributor that reps Intel, you can also try going through their Intel FAE (Field Applications Engineer).

Comment: FYI I applied for access with Intel, but we were ultimately declined. I provided a few requested technical details about our project and requirements, but ultimately I think they would have preferred to see a higher-volume product closer to production. We are just developing our internal prototypes for R&D.

Comment: Sorry to vent, but this is very annoying... I'm new to the EE game, but as an individual, trying to create a very niche product, the additional hoops I need to get through that Intel imposes makes this almost impossible. And the technology has become pretty wide-spread at this point, this should be more open than it is...